# HttpWebRequest.GetResponseStream returns an empty string

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, meta

I have been trying every way possible to download get the response stream from a page using `HttpWebRequest`, which works fine on everything else but no this page. As you see the data returned is an HTML but it have a some meta tag which I am not expert in, but what ever i try to get this block

```
{"error":4,"message":"Unsupported link format or unsupported hoster"}
```

It seems that I can't, I tried to specify the GET content-type as "text/json" but nothing helped.

Below is the HTML content returned when I open the page on the browser, but in code it returns empty string.

```
    <html>
    <meta style="visibility: hidden !important; display: block !important; width: 0px !important; height: 0px !important; border-style: none !important;"></meta>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"error":4,"message":"Unsupported link format or unsupported hoster"}
      </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Edit:

I have tried copy the same html above in a page on localhost and tried to fetch it's content and it actually worked, could there maybe some restriction in the IIS that could prevent fetching content ?

Comment: Does that page load when you open it on a browser? If so, try to replicate all the headers you may be missing (Referrer, User-Agent, etc.)

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Are you triying to automate a download from a direct-dowload site like NowDownload.eu or similar?

Comment: Sounds like it may be a referrer problem. What's the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have evidence that the problem is with the client? The more appropriate question is: Why is the server sending this strange content? The client just receives whatever the server sends.

I suggest you debug the server to find out, or ask a new question containing your server-side code and asking specifically about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `WebRequest` class. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) you find the documentation for it.

You have this example in the page:

```
// Create a request for the URL.        
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("[your_url]");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content. 
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Cleanup the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

This will print in `Console` the HTML content of that page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause was that I previously had set the method to `HEAD` and in later revisions had the need to parse the body.